# GitLab CI: Is it possible to restrict artifact downloads in a matrix?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm wondering if it's possible to only download specific artifacts generated from a previous matrix job. So not every job in the next matrix downloads every single artifacts from all previous matrix jobs.

Example would be:

**Pipeline**:

**Composer Matrix (generating artifacts)**:

- composer-job1
- composer-job2
- composer-job3

**Frontend Matrix (downloading artifacts from composer matrix)**:

- frontend-job1 (only downloads artifacts from composer-job1)
- frontend-job2 (only downloads artifacts from composer-job2)
- frontend-job3 (only downloads artifacts from composer-job3)

**At the moment all artifacts get downloaded and "dependencies" or "needs" don't work for matrix as far as I tested.**

Comment: Can you post a short `.gitlab-ci.yml` example? The `needs` syntax should be fine in this scenario.

Comment: @Rekovni The problem is that you cannot use "needs" with a variable neither can you specify a job generated from a matrix in your "needs" even without a variable.